# is that necessary for makefile to generate .o files for small projects

Tags: makefile

```
all: hello

hello: main.o
 g++ -o hello main.o

main.o: main.cpp
 g++ -c main.cpp
```

Above is a simple makefile, my question is that why we do not use the following for small project? It is no need to generate .o files. Is there any disadvantage of using the following format for small projects?

```
all: hello

hello:main.cpp
 g++ -o hello main.cpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no disadvantage.

[Of course, simple projects have a tendency to grow into bigger projects, so there's always an argument that you should start as you mean to go on...]